# Как в angular 2 передавать данные между компонетами

Tags: angular2

С дочернего в родительский я то знаю через EventEmitter, но если у меня есть много глубоко вложеных компонентов то как сделать?

Comment: Слышали про `redux`? Для `angular 2` есть `ngrx`


 https://github.com/ngrx/store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется что проще всего сделать это через сервис. А в компоненте котором тебе будет нужно использовать эти данные сделать импорт этого сервиса в конструкторе и отобразить нужные данные в template. Если я правильно понял вопрос..=)

Answer (score 0):

1. Используя директиву @Input https://metanit.com/web/angular2/2.7.php
2. Используя сервисы 
   https://metanit.com/web/angular2/4.3.php и подписка на события

https://habrahabr.ru/post/318480/

3. Используя статические классы и подписка на события или список с нужными компонентами

[Angular 2 EventEmitter событие вызывается, но данные не обновляются](https://habrahabr.ru/post/318480/)